# Graphile/starter, docker mode -- changes aren't reflected in browser?

Tags: docker, postgraphile

I'm new to docker development and experimenting with Graphile/starter in docker mode. I've got it up and running with no issues and I've got the project open in a VSCode container as well.

My potentially dumb question is, why aren't my HMTL or sass changes reflected in the browser. It seems I have to stop and restart the project to see changes(?)

Comment: Gotta throw out the most basic question first, just in case (can't hurt); are ya hitting `ctrl+F5` in your browser after making the changes?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Yeah, tried all manner of soft and hard refreshing. :/